# implementation of syncml over http in mtk framework

Tags: mobile-application, syncml

I have to **implement syncml** (syncml client) in **mtk framework**, since mtk phones support syncml and it perform using OBEX . But we have to implements with http ,that is syncml over http .

I don't know how it done in mtk framework .Also i want to know how i create syncml server  plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncml is supported by MTK and you do not need implement your own.
Just turn on SYNCML_SUPPORT in makefile.
If any compile error occurs after SYNCML_SUPPORT turned on, you will need to contact MTK to release a new software with SYNCML_SUPPORT supported.